# Dell Inspiron laptop cannot wake from sleep in Linux

Tags: arch-linux, suspend, laptop, acpi

Name says it all, I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3525 that cannot resume from sleep in Linux whether caused by invoking `systemctl suspend` or by closing/opening the lid. There are many problems similar to mine, however none of the solutions I have found do function. For example most are fixed with nvidia drivers (no nvidia here) or by enabling `lid` in acpi (no lid listed as shown below). Does anyone have advice without digging into DSDT modifications? My attempts at that result in hundreds of errors that I lack the knowledge to fix.

Here is my neofetch information:

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
Host: Inspiron 15 3525 1.3.0 
Kernel: 5.18.3-zen1-1-zen 
Uptime: 13 mins 
Packages: 1061 (pacman), 7 (flatpak) 
Shell: zsh 5.9 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 42.2 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5625U with Radeon Graphics (12) @ 2.300GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI 03:00.0 Barcelo 
Memory: 1895MiB / 7289MiB
```

Here is my /proc/acpi/wakeup:

```
❯ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GPP0      S4    *disabled
GPP1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.2
GP17      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
```

Interestingly, LID is not shown as a device. That being said, when I close the lid the laptop will sleep.

Unsure if it's relevant but I am running secure boot in order to power on my annoying windows 11 encrypted drive. I turned off mok verification so I always get a small `booting in insecure mode` during power on.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
free -m output:

```
❯ free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            7289        1605        4771          48         912        5393
Swap:           8191           0        8191
```

Comment: You need at least as much swap as you have RAM to be able to hibernate. The terminal commands `free` , `man pm-is-supported mkswap swapon` will help.

Comment: @waltinator, thanks for the response but I added my free -m output and my swap file exceeds my ram size
EDIT as I type this I thought of something I should try in regards to the hibernate function, I believe archwiki had something about kernel flags for swapfiles...

Answer (score 3):

Turns out for my particular use case, the solution is to forgo sleep entirely as I think Dell ACPI just does not like Linux. Properly implementing hibernate worked. Thanks to waltinator for sparking my memory!

Here are my steps (All stolen from [ArchWiki hibernate](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate) of course):

1. identify and setup kernel parameters resume=UUID=... and resume_offset=...
2. add resume HOOK to /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
3. modify /etc/systemd/sleep.conf to prevent suspend and allow hibernation
4. modify /etc/systemd/logind.conf to make the lid cause a hibernation event
5. add /etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf to reduce system swappiness to 10
6. enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Install [Tweaks](https://helpmanual.io/packages/apt/gnome-tweaks/), and slide the suspend off. 
See [Why does my computer turn off when I close the lid?](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-closelid.html.en) for details.